# Composite component does not support event null

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to add a p:confirm inside a composite commandButton, but the following error is issued:

```
<p:confirm> Composite component does not support event null
```

When I change to plain p:commandButton it works.

Also, when used directly inside a composite commandLink (exactly with the same attributes), using the same p:confirmDialog (global), it works.

Usage example:

```xhtml
<myCompositeSuite:commandButton id="buttonId"
    action="#{beanController.action}">
    <p:confirm
        header="Confirm"
        message="Do you confirm this action?"
        icon="ui-icon-alert" />
</myCompositeSuite:commandButton>
```

Composite component example (what I tried is in comments):

```xhtml
<cc:interface name="commandButton">
    <cc:attribute name="rendered" default="true" />
    <cc:attribute name="value" default="Button" />
    <cc:attribute name="title" />
    <cc:attribute name="style" />
    <cc:attribute name="styleClass" />
    <cc:attribute name="disabled" default="false" />
    <cc:attribute name="ajax" default="false" />
    <cc:attribute name="process" />
    <cc:attribute name="onclick" />
    <cc:attribute name="action" targets="myCompositeButton" />
    <cc:attribute name="immediate" default="false" />
    <cc:attribute name="oncomplete" />
    <cc:attribute name="update" />

    <cc:actionSource name="command" targets="myCompositeButton" />

    <cc:clientBehavior name="click" targets="myCompositeButton" event="click" />
    <!-- <cc:clientBehavior name="confirm" targets="myCompositeButton" event="null" /> -->
    <!-- <cc:clientBehavior name="null" targets="myCompositeButton" event="null" /> -->
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
    <p:commandButton id="myCompositeButton"
        rendered="#{cc.attrs.rendered}"
        value="#{cc.attrs.value}"
        title="#{cc.attrs.title}"   
        immediate="#{cc.attrs.immediate}"
        styleClass="#{cc.attrs.styleClass}"
        style="#{cc.attrs.style}"
        disabled="#{cc.attrs.disabled}"
        onclick="#{cc.attrs.onclick};"
        oncomplete="#{cc.attrs.oncomplete};"
        ajax="#{cc.attrs.ajax}"
        process="#{cc.attrs.process}"
        update="#{cc.attrs.update}">

        <cc:insertChildren />
    </p:commandButton>
</cc:implementation>
```

I'm using jsf version 2.3 and primefaces version 6.2.